# Jmeter executing scripts but provides blank report

Tags: linux, docker, server, jmeter

I am running jmeter in non GUI mode in my linux server inside docker. When I check jmeter is installed or not it says its there with the version but when I execute my script it says as follows-

```
root@xxxxxxx:/# /var/xxxxx/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter -n -t /lib/xxx/deduction.jmx -l test.jtl
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /lib/xxx.s/deduction.jmx
Starting the test @ Tue May 14 05:54:53 UTC 2019 (1557813293320)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up ...    @ Tue May 14 05:55:53 UTC 2019 (1557813353945)
... end of run
```

The same file works fine in my windows machine.

```
root@xxxxxx:/# /var/xxxxxx/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter -v
    _    ____   _    ____ _   _ _____       _ __  __ _____ _____ _____ ____
   / \  |  _ \ / \  / ___| | | | ____|     | |  \/  | ____|_   _| ____|  _ \
  / _ \ | |_) / _ \| |   | |_| |  _|    _  | | |\/| |  _|   | | |  _| | |_) |
 / ___ \|  __/ ___ \ |___|  _  | |___  | |_| | |  | | |___  | | | |___|  _ <
/_/   \_\_| /_/   \_\____|_| |_|_____|  \___/|_|  |_|_____| |_| |_____|_| \_\ 5.1 r1853635

Copyright (c) 1999-2019 The Apache Software Foundation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced that also. In my case, the problem was the path set on JMeter component “CSV Data Set Config”. When I executed the project at my machine, the Jmeter searched and found the path, but after upload to the server I forgot to change the CSV path according to the server environment. After change it the tests were executed Ok on server. So, check if there is something like that on your JMeter project.